# Undefined variable: error on localhost with xampp

Tags: php, apache, joomla, xampp

I am using xampps and Joomla 3. 
I'm running it on localhost. I am getting this error on my main page. However, the website is still working like normal. I don't know what is the issue.

**Error Message Shown Below:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: userData in C:\xampp\htdocs\wegodivetest\modules\mod_jhotelreservation\helper.php on line 35

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wegodivetest\modules\mod_jhotelreservation\helper.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined variable: userData in C:\xampp\htdocs\wegodivetest\modules\mod_jhotelreservation\helper.php on line 35

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wegodivetest\modules\mod_jhotelreservation\helper.php on line 35
```

Comment: Please show us the code that is causing this error.

Comment: As the error messages say: `$userData` is not defined, which means it has no value. We can't help you more than that without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi David Yue, I don't have the code. I am not a programmer. I just copy my either website from the host server and duplicate in on my localhost.

Comment: @chop - If you have the site on your localhost, then you have the code. Therefore please provide the code from the file that's causing the error

Comment: Hi Lodder, how could I copy the codes and let u see. which file is the code store? and do I need another software to open the codes?